# Friendly ID and Rails Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, friendly-id

I followed the steps to get friendly_id working in the rails engine - which are posted [here on github](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart) and it seems that when I do the following:

```
  s.add_dependency 'friendly_id', '~> 5.0.0'
```

in the engine.gemspec file and then do:

```
bundle install #=> works
rails g friendly_id #=> works
rake db:migrate
```

I get:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant FriendlyId
```

Um .... What?

## Update - Modal with FriendlyId

```
  module Xaaron
     class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
        extend FriendlyId
        friendly_id :role, use: :slugged

        validates :role, presence: true
        validates_uniqueness_of :role
      end
   end
```

Comment: Show you model with frendlyId

Comment: What is your rails and ruby versions?

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0] and rails 4.0.3 (not sure how this helps) @zishe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to explicitly require FriendlyId from your engine ([docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#other-gem-dependencies)):

```
require 'friendly_id'
```